# Install shield taking time in ResolveSource

Tags: installation, windows-installer, installshield, installshield-2016

Installing our software in certain machines is taking too much of time. When looking the install logs, the time is showing in ResolveSource custom action.
The problem is not happening in all machines. It's happening very rarely in certain PC's.
What could be the problem on why this installshield custom action is taking more time? See the below logs, it took 13 minutes to complete the action.

```
MSI (s) (E0:F0) [10:37:47:182]: Doing action: ResolveSource
Action 10:37:47: ResolveSource. 
Action start 10:37:47: ResolveSource.
MSI (s) (E0:F0) [10:37:47:182]: Resolving source.
MSI (s) (E0:F0) [10:37:47:182]: Resolving source to launched-from source.
MSI (s) (E0:F0) [10:37:47:182]: Setting launched-from source as last-used.
MSI (s) (E0:F0) [10:37:47:182]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SourceDir property. Its value is '<Installation path>'.
MSI (s) (E0:F0) [10:37:47:182]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SOURCEDIR property. Its value is '<Installation path>'.
MSI (s) (E0:F0) [10:37:47:182]: PROPERTY CHANGE: Adding SourcedirProduct property. Its value is '{3c582223-4ab3-4e42-ac22-f1d39dbc9ebe}'.
MSI (s) (E0:F0) [10:37:47:182]: SOURCEDIR ==> <Installation path>
MSI (s) (E0:F0) [10:37:47:182]: SOURCEDIR product ==> {3c582223-4ab3-4e42-ac22-f1d39dbc9ebe}
MSI (s) (E0:F0) [10:37:47:182]: Determining source type
MSI (s) (E0:F0) [10:37:47:202]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (E0:F0) [10:37:47:202]: Source type from package 'Setup.msi': 0
MSI (s) (E0:F0) [10:37:47:202]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (s) (E0:F0) [10:37:47:202]: SECREPAIR: Hash Database: C:\WINDOWS\Installer\SourceHash{3c582223-4ab3-4e42-ac22-f1d39dbc9ebe}
MSI (s) (E0:F0) [10:37:47:202]: SECREPAIR: SourceHash database file already exists. Deleting it.
MSI (s) (E0:F0) [10:37:47:212]: Note: 1: 2262 2: SourceHash 3: -2147287038 
MSI (s) (E0:F0) [10:37:47:212]: SECREPAIR: New Hash Database creation complete.
MSI (s) (E0:F0) [10:37:47:322]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (s) (E0:F0) [10:50:02:921]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
```